# xcode 6 zoomToRect animated issue

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, ios8

I got a photo gallery app an have an issue getting ready for ios 8.
The images are displayed in a UIPageViewController and every page has a view with a custom UIScrollView class. It's just like Apples PhotoScroller Sample (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html)

I added a UITapGestureRecognizer for double tapping. Here's the code i use for zooming:

```
- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
if (self.minimumZoomScale == self.maximumZoomScale) return;
if (self.zoomScale == self.minimumZoomScale) didDoubleTap = NO;

CGPoint pointInView = [recognizer locationInView:_zoomView];

CGFloat newZoomScale;
if (!didDoubleTap && self.zoomScale <= self.minimumZoomScale) {
    newZoomScale = self.zoomScale * 2.5f;
    newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.maximumZoomScale);
    didDoubleTap = YES;
}
else {
    newZoomScale = self.minimumZoomScale;
    didDoubleTap = NO;
}

CGSize scrollViewSize = self.bounds.size;

CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
CGFloat x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0f);
CGFloat y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0f);

CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
[self zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];
}
```

This works when i run it on xcode 5.1 perfectly, like in any other photo apps. But when i run / build it on xcode 6 gm the animation for the zoom gets wierd. First the content offset is set to the future location, and then it zooms in. So the images is jumping up or down.

anyone had this issue before or have any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

okay i found a workaround. the problem is the animation calls `layoutsubviews` before the zooming. so now i do my own animation

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^ {
    inTransition = YES;
    [self zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:NO];
    inTransition = NO;
    [self layoutSubviews];
} completion:nil];
```

but it would be nice if anyone could tell me why i have to do that.

**EDIT:**
If someone's still interested, move the code from `layoutsubviews` to`scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`. So there's no need for that weird animation an pinch to zoom also works smoothly.

Comment: You set inTranstion to YES and then to NO. Is it critical to this solution?

Comment: This workaround works for me too. But there is the same bugs when zooming with pan gesture. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I found the same bug when zooming with pinch gesture.
I solved this by calling layoutSubviews in scrollViewDidScroll delegate method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: I just juse this in    layoutSubviews
    `if (self.zoomScale < self.minimumZoomScale) return;`

Comment: Thanks! Calling `[myScrollView layoutSubviews]` in `- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;` when using `[myScrollView setZoomScale:myScale animated:YES];` fixed it for me in an old app.